# Plotting the result of interpolation

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I have a h5 file containing regulargrid data. I have used a code by which I can easily get the interpolated value for three given value. I have used RegularGridInterpolator function for interpolation purpose here. Now I want to make a plot to check whether the interpolation is correct or not. But I don't understand how can I do that. Can anyone help me to do that please? Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np   
import h5py
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
f = h5py.File('file.h5', 'r')  
list(f.keys())
dset = f[u'data']
dset.shape
dset.value.shape
dset[0:63,0:63,0:63]
x = np.linspace(-10, 320, 64) 
y = np.linspace(-10, 320, 64)
z = np.linspace(-10, 320, 64)
my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), dset.value)
pts = np.array([7.36970468e-09, -4.54271563e-09, 1.51802701e-09])
my_interpolating_function(pts)
```

The output of the interpolation is array([5.45534467e-10])

Comment: Looks to me like you have asked for the interpolated value at one point, defined by the 3 values of `pts`.  Does that look like a reasonable value at the point?

Comment: Yes, I have already interpolated and found this result for three given values.